# How to plot this spectrum?

Tags: plotting

Please, I want to know which code to use to plot a spectrum like this.

Need examples for more details please.

[image: Spectrum]

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Try `DensityPlot` or `ListDensityPlot` with option `ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"`.

Comment: This looks like measurement data stored in arrays. So `ListDensityPlot` might be the better choice.

Comment: Thank you so much @Henrik .

Comment: You're welcome.